# Can I keep two versions of maven build?

Tags: java, maven

I have three projects using maven(A,B). I used one maven(A) project as a dependency to others(B,C). I made some changes to A to for the developing purposes of B. But I don't need them in C and it will create an error. Is there any possibility that I can keep two or more version of Project A to support project B and C at the same moment.

Comment: Sure, publish the two versions on your repository. What's the issue you're having?

Comment: The problem is I'm deploying the projects on server. For once or twice a month local repository is cleaned by resource team.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your builds create an artifact with version number. So you can declare a dependency to different versions of A in your projects B and C.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not very clear Meier. Can I keep two artifacts from same pom.xml?

Comment: Okay I get it. But the problem is if local repository is cleared, older version maybe vanish. Am I correct?

Comment: That is true. But you should not use the local repository as permanent repository anyway. Instead, you need a Nexus/Artifactory to which you deploy the artifacts. In the Nexus/Artifactory you can keep as many versions as you want.